# Selenium + Python. Выбрать необходимый элемент из выпадающего списка

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет. Необходимо перебрать элементы выпадающего списка и выбрать с нужным текстом. Select не работает.

```
        one = self._browser.find_element(локатор_первого_элемента)
        if one.text == 'х':
            one.click()
        two = self._browser.find_element(локатор_второго_элемента)
        if two.text == 'х':
            two.click()
        three = self._browser.find_element(локатор_третьего_элемента)
        if three.text == 'х':
            three.click()
        four = self._browser.find_element(локатор_четвертого_элемента)
        if four.text == 'х':
            four.click()
```

Но это я не совсем правильно сделал. Он находит нужную кнопку и выбирает её, но проблема в том, что код идёт дальше проверять, а если в списке 3 элемента, а не 4 как указано, то вылетает ошибка 'Не найден элемент'. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.
Цикл for пытался сделать, но не вышло

Answer (score 1):

Для примера возьмём сайт https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/basic-html-form-test.html

**Общий код для всех вариантов:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  # для 3 варианта эта строка не нужна 


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://testpages.herokuapp.com/styled/basic-html-form-test.html")
WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "dropdown")))
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "dropdown")
dropdown.click()
```

А далее есть варианты:

**Вариант 1**

```
se = Select(dropdown)  # dropdown = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "dropdown")
dropdown_item4 = se.select_by_visible_text('Drop Down Item 4')
```

**Вариант 2**

```
se = Select(dropdown)  # dropdown = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "dropdown")
for item in se.options:
    if item.text == 'Drop Down Item 5':
        item.click()
        break
```

**Вариант 3**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "option[value='dd1']")))
# select[name=dropdown] option[value] - общий CSS селектор для всех вариантов в меню
dropdown_items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name=dropdown] option[value]")
for item in dropdown_items:
    if item.text == 'Drop Down Item 6':
        item.click()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже писал, Select в данном случае не работает из-за того, что выпадающий список представлен как отдельный веб-элемент, а не интегрирован в сайт, как например кнопки. Проблему решил простым циклом for, оставлю его здесь, если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой.

```
list_elements_text = [elements.text for elements in (локатор_выпадающего списка)]
for elements in list_elements_text:
   if list_elements_text[0] == 'x':
      (локатор_кнопки_1).click()
      break
   if list_elements_text[1] == 'x':
      (локатор_кнопки_2).click()
      break
   if list_elements_text[2] == 'x':
      (локатор_кнопки_3).click()
      break
   if list_elements_text[3] == 'x':
      (локатор_кнопки_4).click()
      break
```